# Properly create an sha512 checksum in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create sha512 encoded string in ruby for using with my payment gateway. This is format needed.

> sha512
>   (key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||SALT)

I was also told to use 11 empty pipes between email and salt if  not using any udf.
So in the controller I created the checksum like this

```
require 'digest/sha2'

SEPARATOR = '|'
DIVIDER = SEPARATOR * 11

def get_checksum(params)
    str = params.values_at(
        :key, :txnid, :amount, :productinfo, :firstname, :email
    ).join(SEPARATOR) + DIVIDER + 'salt'

    Digest::SHA512.hexdigest( str )
  end
```

But the server is telling checksum failed. I think this is because I am not creating the checksum properly as expected by the server..Is the `require 'digest/sha2'`the right one to use for SHA512??

Comment: What is `SEPARATOR` and `DIVIDER`? Do you set `udf1` .. `udf5`? You add the string `'salt'`, but there is no `salt` in the expected format.

Comment: Does the above method return the string you expect it to? Does the payment gateway API documentation tell you what format it expects the hash in? I'm guessing hex is correct but it might not be. Do the API docs give you any examples of valid input and the corresponding output?

Comment: @Jordan yes I am getting a hash. All the payment gateway telling me is that the hash need to be in this format  "sha512 (key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||)"

Comment: @spickermann sperator and divider are just '|'. and salt is a string i put there directly

Comment: @spickermann updated my answer to address the things you asked for.

Comment: Are you sure your string is supposed to have the literal string `salt` in it? In cryptography the ["salt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is usually some value unique to your application or account. It would be a pretty bad practice for the salt to be the literal word "salt".

Comment: I think the salt is your problem. I believe you need to replace `SALT` with a string provided to you by the payment gateway.

Comment: @Jordan Actually am using the string..here i changed it as its sensitive

Comment: @spickermann need 11 empty pipes if not using udf, which I am...

Comment: Are you using PayU India? Have you looked at their [Ruby on Rails Integration Kit](https://github.com/payu-india/payumoney-integration-kit-ror)? Its [`PayuIn.checksum`](https://github.com/payu-india/payumoney-integration-kit-ror/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=checksum) method may be instructive (you can see how it's called [here](https://github.com/payu-india/payumoney-integration-kit-ror/blob/533d93551489d2994dbcdf8c7bd1854bdcf3286b/PayU/lib/active_merchant/payu_in/helper.rb#L46-L63)).

Comment: @Jordan Yes I am..but am using payumoney..Their integration kit is outdated..My app fails to start after adding their gem..So I removed it..

Answer (score 0):

I think that require 'digest' should work

Comment: using rubymine and its warning me.."cant find sha512 for type DIgest"....This warning makes me think that am doing it wrong..

Comment: I just tested it in my console
   $ irb
    irb(main):001:0> require 'digest'
    => true
    irb(main):002:0> Digest::SHA512.hexdigest('asadsadsdas')
    => "79f5d76f13ad5862c15e5f3e7370f507db2f06af8e0ca5a98976bc790aea1cee353ce577a0e32c226310c5b375084f1f43ecf15d6a8297c70664180bed696081"

Comment: maybe you have an old version of ruby? Or an old version of the gem?

Comment: Yes even I get the hash

Comment: The problem is that I cant get it working with my payment gateway..when i send a request with this its telling checksum failed.

Comment: so i thought i might be doing something wrong as they may be calculating it differently

Comment: Are you sure str is a string? Maybe do str.to_s

Comment: tried to_s but still same..If the sha512 implementation here is correct then i think it should be something else(maybe their issue)